# Get Pacific Time in Ruby without Rails or installing gems

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

In Ruby, I want to get the *current* Pacific Time, without having to worry if it’s in Daylight Savings or not. I can get either `PST` or `PDT` just fine:

```
Time.parse('7am PST')
Time.parse('7am PDT')
```

But I’m having no luck getting Pacific time in general. I’ve tried `Pacific`, `US/Pacific`, `PT`, and a bunch of others.

Is there a way to figure out if current Pacific Time is `PST` or `PDT` using a vanila Ruby installation (i.e. no Rails or downloading gems)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ENV['TZ']` variable can be set to work with `Ruby`'s `Time` in the specified timezone:

```
ENV['TZ'] = 'US/Pacific'
Time.now # => 2018-09-09 07:22:30 -0700
Time.local(2018, 9, 9, 7, 20) # => 2018-09-09 07:20:00 -0700
Time.local(2018, 3, 9, 7, 20) # => 2018-03-09 07:20:00 -0800
```